# Are there applications of Hyperbolic Programming other than Linear Programming and Semidefinite programming?

Tags: linear-programming, semidefinite-programming

Title. It seems the most important special cases are LPs and SDPs. Are there other interesting special cases/applications for hyperbolic programming? (Apart from being super cool math on of itself)

I am assuming the answer is a function of our confidence in the general Lax’s conjecture (essentially saying SDPs are equivalent to hyperbolic programming), but I do not know to what extent the community believes that conjecture to be true.

Comment: can you provide a link or a definition of hyperbolic programming?